# Typescript infer that field is truthy(cannot be undefined), without user-defined type guards

Tags: typescript, undefined, type-inference, typeguards

```
type Item = {
    left?: { photoSrc: string };
};

type ItemRequired = {
    left: { photoSrc: string };
};

const item: Item = {} as any;

if (item.left) {
    const itemRequired: ItemRequired = item; // fails. Typescript still says left may be undefined
    // I'd like Typescript to know that field left is truthy
}
```

I know about user-defined type guards. E.g.

```
function isFish(pet: Fish | Bird): pet is Fish {
  return (pet as Fish).swim !== undefined;
}
```

My questions:

1. Why is Typescript unable to infer that `left` cannot be undefined?
2. Does that mean I need to create a type guard function for every variation of a type I need to check? Isn't there a simpler way? E.g. I expect when inside the scope of an if check that proves that `left` field cannot be undefined, I expect Typescript to know that.

This seems like a very common case, but I couldn't find the answer, please excuse me if there is one.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions:

I'm presuming because Typescript is here making a comparison between the two types: `Item` and `ItemRequired`, rather than what you'd like, which is `{ left:{ photoSrc:string } }`.

Typescript can often figure out what part of union types your using *without* type guards, but it's not yet quite perfect. It's situational as to which will and won't work, there are a great deals of possible situations.

A lot of the time people want to get away without type guards, and that's understandable as often it seems like additional, unnecessary code. But it's really designed for this exact situation:

```js
const itemIsItemRequired = (item: Item): item is ItemRequired =>
  item.left !== undefined;

if (itemIsItemRequired(item)) {
    const itemRequired: ItemRequired = item; // this works
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, Typescript does not infer types from the **conditional flow of statements**.

```
const item: Item = {} as any;
if (item.left) {
    const itemRequired: ItemRequired = item; 
}
```

As a result, the above code block does not actually narrow the item type from `Item` to `ItemRequired`. Hence, to the compiler, you are trying to assign two incompatible types - one where left is mandatory and other where it is optional.

An alternative, as you mentioned, you can write a type guard or simply, you can do the following.

```
const itemRequired: ItemRequired = item as ItemRequired;
```

However, writing type guards is always recommended.

Comment: "*Typescript does not infer types from the conditional flow of statements*" - this seems wrong or at least outdated. It may not do it here, but it does in general, for at least some (simple) cases.